# RealURL and tt_news multiple Singleviews

Tags: typo3, detailsview, tt-news, realurl, typo3-4.5

I have a typo3 with multiple trees (one per language) under a common root and domain,

```
www.example.com (maintemplate)
-en (+ext)
--news
---singleview(hidden)
-fr (+ext)
--french_news
---singleview(hidden)
-de (+ext)
--german_news
---singleview(hidden)
-Newsfolder
--english
--french
--german
```

the tt_news.SinglePID is configured via constants in the extension templates.
My Problem is, that Realurl always uses the SinglePID from the english tree, for example when I click on a german news entry Realurl brings me to the english page and shows the german news. Any Idea how to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the single pid with the TypoScript instead of form and then use [common conditions](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/4.7/Conditions/ConditionReference/Index.html) for changing it

Comment: at the moment there is a file constants_de.ts which is loaded for the german tree, and in the tt_news.ts file (which is loaded at root) where SinglePID is defined by the constant, all content has the same language id, how could i use conditions in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a RealURL issue? Turn it off via TypoScript setup `config.tx_realurl_enable = 0` to see whether it's buggy even without RealURL manipulating your urls or not.

Regarding your issue try this in your global TypoScript constants:

```
plugin.tt_news.singlePid = x
[PIDinRootline = a]
plugin.tt_news.singlePid = y
[PIDinRootline = b]
plugin.tt_news.singlePid = z
[global]
```

Whereby x is the uid of the english single page, y the german one, z the french one. And a and b the root pages of those trees.